# Можно ли заменить чем-то time. Чтобы бы браузер сам не закрывался?

Tags: python, selenium

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")

articles = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="articlecount"]/a[1]')

search = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'search')
search.send_keys('Python')
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: попробуй добавить в вопрос больше текста, чтобы он стал понятным для простых людей

Comment: А чем вас time не устроил?

Comment: Вообще как-то нужно доформулировать вопрос. Я так понимаю, что нужно чего-то ждать. Но чего - пока кто-то браузер не закроет? Или браузер должен остаться вечно висеть? Или какая цель то?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67740304/15035314

Comment: @АлексейР Спасибо Большое!